# Ambiguity in the property that opposite angles of a cyclic quadrilaterals are supplementary

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral, convention

Consider a convex cyclic quadrilateral ABCD.

A basic property of one such quadrilateral is that $\measuredangle \, BCD + \measuredangle \, DAB = 180^{\circ}$.

One way to settle this equality is by resorting to the inscribed angle theorem: indeed, if $O$ is the center of the circumference passing through $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$, then

$\measuredangle \, BCD + \measuredangle \, DAB = \frac{1}{2}\left(\measuredangle \, BOD + \measuredangle \, DOB\right)$.

The conclusion follows from the previous line because,  if we measure the angles $\angle \, BOD$ and $\angle \, DOB$ **in a proper way**, we get that $\measuredangle \, BOD + \measuredangle \, DOB = 360^{\circ}$.

What's the convention about angle measurement that needs to be made in order to **unambiguously** ascertain that $\measuredangle \, BOD + \measuredangle \, DOB = 360^{\circ}$? The thing is that if one doesn't look at $\angle \, DOB$ from the right perspective (so to speak), one may end up saying $\measuredangle \, BOD=\measuredangle \, DOB$ (instead of $\measuredangle \, BOD + \measuredangle \, DOB = 360^{\circ}$).

Hope you don't find this question too näive for this site.

Thanks in advance for your comments, suggestions, and replies.

Comment: There is only one way to look at $\angle DOB$. Yes if we said $\angle O$, that would be ambiguous. Or may be I have not understood your question. If you can add a diagram, that may help.

Comment: $\angle \, DOB$ does imply that we measure from the ray thru $D$ and $O$ to the ray thru $B$ and $O$?

Comment: @Jamai-Con When you write $\angle DAB = \frac{1}{2} \angle DOB$ you measure $\angle DOB$ along the arc subtended by $\angle DAB$, and there is no ambiguity about it.

Comment: @Jamai-Con it is angle between rays $OB$ and $OD$, and we write it as either $\angle DOB$ or $\angle BOD$.

Comment: @dxiv, mathlover: It sort of surprises me that you mention that there are no ambiguities here... Let us not take arcs or some other notion into account. What is the angle that the largest needle of a clock and the minute hand make at 5:48 A.M.? Can this question be answered unambiguously without introducing a convention concerning angle measurement first?

Comment: @Jamai-Con The central angle $\angle DOB$ is not defined by just the two points $D$, $B$ but by the arc it subtends. The two points define two arcs $\overparen{DAB}$ and $\overparen{DCB}$. Angle $\angle DAB$ subtends the arc $\overparen{DCB}$ which contains the opposite vertex $C$, so when you write $\angle DAB = \frac{1}{2} \angle DOB$ the central angle on the RHS is the one that subtends the same arc $\overparen{DCB}$, and there is no ambiguity about it.

Comment: @Jamai-Con The usual formulation of the [inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) is that "*an angle θ inscribed in a circle is half of the central angle 2θ that* ***subtends the same arc*** *on the circle*". There is no ambiguity here as to *which* central angle you refer to when using the theorem. You should [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4160351/edit) the question and literally quote the form of the theorem that *you* are using which supposedly leaves room to the ambiguity you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Your question involves the naming convention of an angle.

"An angle whose size is between $90^0$ and $180^0$ shoudl be prefixed with the word 'reflex'."

Refering the the figure attached.

[image]

$\alpha' = \angle BOD = \angle DOB$.

$\gamma'$ should be named as "reflex $\angle BOD$ or reflex $\angle DOB$.

Added: In geobegra, the naming convention of an angle is anti-cloclockwise. Thus, saying $\angle DOB$ yields $\alpha'$; while saying $\angle BOD$ yields $\gamma'$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Now focus on the figure. I definitely agree with you that here $\angle BOD = \angle DOB $. You are 100% correct in that. Well I don't know about you but I have just gone through standard 9 and that time our teacher told that it is $\measuredangle \, BCD + \measuredangle \, DAB = \frac{1}{2}\left(\measuredangle \, BOD + \text{reflex} \measuredangle \, BOD\right)$. So this should be the formula because $ \angle BOD = \angle DOB$ is not $360$ unless we take one to be non reflex and other as reflex angle leaving the straight line case. Our teacher also told us that many times it is written $BOD+DOB$. In those places you have to assume $BOD$ to be non reflex angle an $DOB$ to be the reflex angle. Sometimes it might be opposite too.

You can also look at the proof [here](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/prove-that-the-sum-of-opposite-angles-of-a-cyclic/). Do remember that arcs plays a good amount of role in this proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot for entering your answer... One question and one observation: what do you mean by "standard nine"? On the other hand, my native tongue is not English; to be a hundred percent honest, I had not seen the phrase "reflex BOD" in the past. I have been thinking that the easiest way to prevent any ambiguities is to say, right from the start, something like this: heretofore, the angle BOD is measured from BO to DO in the counterclockwise direction and the angle DOB from DO to OB in the same direction.

Comment: In this way, we don't need to  consider some additional notions like "reflex Mr. So and So" or "arc subtendend by a certain angle", etc. What do you think about this?

Comment: @Jamai-Con standard 9 means in school in class 9. Ya you are thinking right about BOD. If there is a angle $BOD$ of measured $60$ degree then the reflex $BOD$ would be $360-BOD$ which is $360-60$.

Comment: @Jamai-Con for your second message ya we won't need but we need the theorem Angle subtended in centre is twice at any other path

Comment: One of my points is that we can also formulate that theorem without talking about arcs; we only need to learn how to associate a central angle to any inscribed angle but that's no biggie...

Comment: @Jamai-Con ya correct

Comment: For some reason, it is not that natural to me to pass from the inscribed angle to the arc, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126290/discussion-between-jitendra-singh-and-jamai-con).

Comment: @Jamai-Con do you have any more doubts? Actually I wanted to have some more chat on that topic with you